# TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: Tensor("concatenate_6/concat:0", shape=(None, 4608), dtype=float32)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement a VQA model in which I'm combining an image and a language model. My model definition is:

```
def VQA_MODEL():
    image_feature_size          = 4096
    word_feature_size           = 300
    number_of_LSTM              = 3
    number_of_hidden_units_LSTM = 512
    max_length_questions        = 30
    number_of_dense_layers      = 3
    number_of_hidden_units      = 1024
    activation_function         = 'tanh'
    dropout_pct                 = 0.5

    # Image model
    model_image = Sequential()
    model_image.add(Reshape((image_feature_size,), input_shape=(image_feature_size,)))

   # Language Model
   model_language = Sequential()
   model_language.add(LSTM(number_of_hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(max_length_questions, word_feature_size)))
   model_language.add(LSTM(number_of_hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=True))  
   model_language.add(LSTM(number_of_hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=False))


   # combined model
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(concatenate([model_language.output, model_image.output]))

   for _ in range(number_of_dense_layers):
       model.add(Dense(number_of_hidden_units, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation= activation_function))
       model.add(Dropout(dropout_pct))

   model.add(Dense(50, activation='softmax'))

   return model

model = VQA_MODEL()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, batch_size = batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch)
```

I can't seem to understand how to resolve the error. Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that `concatenate` with small letter `c` is not a `layer` and only `Concatenate` with capital letter `c` is a layer. However, that will also not work in your case.

Since the your combined model is not `sequential` and uses inputs from two parallel or different models, it's better to use the `Functional` API. The following code should work:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Reshape, Dense, Dropout, concatenate, Concatenate
def VQA_MODEL():
    image_feature_size          = 4096
    word_feature_size           = 300
    number_of_LSTM              = 3
    number_of_hidden_units_LSTM = 512
    max_length_questions        = 30
    number_of_dense_layers      = 3
    number_of_hidden_units      = 1024
    activation_function         = 'tanh'
    dropout_pct                 = 0.5

    # Image model
    model_image = Sequential()
    model_image.add(Reshape((image_feature_size,), input_shape=(image_feature_size,)))

   # Language Model
    model_language = Sequential()
    model_language.add(LSTM(number_of_hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(max_length_questions, word_feature_size)))
    model_language.add(LSTM(number_of_hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=True))  
    model_language.add(LSTM(number_of_hidden_units_LSTM, return_sequences=False))


    # combined model
    x = Concatenate()([model_language.output, model_image.output])

    for _ in range(number_of_dense_layers):
        x = Dense(number_of_hidden_units, kernel_initializer='uniform', activation= activation_function)(x)
        x = Dropout(dropout_pct)(x)
    x = Dense(50, activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs = [model_language.input, model_image.input], outputs=x)
    return model

model = VQA_MODEL()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) 
model.fit(train_X, train_Y, batch_size = batch_size, epochs=nb_epoch)
```